# How to know which sections or rows show up or visible on listnewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to make a program where people can switch from listviewcontroller and map controller.

At a time, out of 100 rows, there are about only 5 - 6 rows shown at a time

How do I know which rows are being shown?

Comment: When do you need to know this? If the user just taps on a cell, a delegate method containing the appropriate NSIndexPath will be called...

Comment: Sometimes the user can see the map version of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableView` has a method called `visibleCells` that returns an array of the currently visible cells.